Why was the question "Fortran loop constructs and avoiding a goto" migrated when someone was already answering?
Why was the question "Fortran loop constructs and avoiding a goto" migrated to Code Review?

Not mentionning in addition that the question was on-topic on SO...

When I saw what had happened my first thought was "is it possible to unmigrate this"

[so], nor any of the other sites in the community, are a "forum"; they are Q&A websites. Forums operate/function quite differently.

On the question here, links are allowed in posts; rather than make us copy the content of the title, put it in a search engine, and find the post, please actually link the post you are querying.


@ThomA, "forum", AMA, Q&A website, ..., whatever.  You understood the intent of my post.  Someone, whom I've never seen in discussions of Fortran questions in SO, moved a topic that had active discussion to a place,forum,q&a website, whatever, where I could no longer respond.  Furthermore, the OP wasn't asking for a code review.  He was asking for help on replacing 60+ year old FORTRAN with modern Fortran constructs.  The original post was on-topic and easily understood by people who know Fortran.

@steve You should be informed that StackOverflow has a high standard for questions asked and answers posted: askers are not entitled to an answer and you as an answerer are not entitled to post an answer if the community decides the question is unsuitable. Perhaps you should peruse the help center.

The question asks within its body "How would you write it (in Fortran) for conciseness, clarity, brevity, maintainability and performance?" which strays too far into soliciting opinion and style (and thus was attempted to be migrated to a sister site designed for it). However, your comment addresses a very practical and concrete aspect of the code shown, namely "How can I avoid goto to jump to next loop iteration" which would be much more properly focused and objectively answerable. If someone thinks there's value there want to hammer the question into that shape, I think they could.

A) Please verify that the question I linked in your question here is the one you're asking about. B) Please chose one of the two questions you've asked for this question to be about. Please [edit] to clarify which you want. #2 is likely a duplicate. If you had an answer on a migrated question, then you would not be able to edit it unilaterally without an account on the site to which it was migrated. However, you don't have an answer on that question, nor, it appears, an answer on any migrated question, so your question #2 appears confusing. You do have a couple of comments. Please clarify.

@kmdreko, I never claimed to be entitled to answer a question.  I do, however, find it rather dubious that someone moved a question that is being actively address to a forum,ama,q&a website,whatever where the individual providing help cannot not longer respond.  The OP was on-topic.

@Makyen the two questions I asked are clear, and are clearly related.  In your rambling response, you've identify the stupidity of migrating a question that never should have been moved.   That is, I can no longer edit my response(s) nor continue to help an individual.  The original post was on-topic for Fortran.  The original post had a response from me that helped the individual discover that Fortran has named constructs, which answered at least a part of his question.

I don't think anyone (including moderators) can see when someone else is typing up an answer.

@steve Thank you for the clarifications. I've reopened this question and pinged in the moderator chat room the moderator who migrated that question, as they are the only person that can actually answer "why".

I strongly concur: although not well formulated, the question was on topic on SO and is actually not on topic on CR. The OP was not asking at all for a code review.

Your intent Initially misunderstood, so no it wasn't clear; I thought you were asking about how you could dispute about content you had written being copied to a forum wohoutput creating an account on that site (which has nothing to do with [so]).

As for about intent or not, it wasn't, it was about educational. You called the sites a forum and talk about the question having a "discussion", but discussions are also pff-topic on [so] (apart from in th awful Discussions area). Using terms like these normally indicates the user doesn't understand how the site operates and/or why it does, and thus often have a poorer experience when using the sites incorrectly.

As far as I'm aware, moderators can't see if someone is in the process of writing an answer to a question (regular users certainly can't). Even if they could or if the answer had already been posted, that would have no bearing on whether the question should be migrated, for the same reason that answers have no bearing on whether a question should be closed.
If the question were off-topic for Stack Overflow, on-topic for Code Review, and met the latter's quality standards, migrating it would be appropriate regardless of any answers it may receive. However, that was evidently not the case in this instance, and it has now been returned to Stack Overflow.

Perhaps, checking timestamps and commentary/interaction between OP and those making comments might be prudent before moving a question.  OP asked the question.  My first comment provide information about Fortran's named do-loop construct.  OP responded he was unaware of named constructs and thanked me.  I responded with a "you're welcomed" and additional information that all block constructs in Fortran can be named.   Time passes (hours? too disinterested to verify).  The question was migrated.  Alienating those taking time to answer questions seems to be good strategy to discourage them.

As I said, none of that matters. The only things that matter for migration are the topicality and quality of the question. If the question had been appropriate for Code Review, you could have just as easily answered it there, I don't see how that's "alienating."

I migrated it because OP had working code, so there was no "problem" with the code to solve, and was asking about refactoring/style, which I believe is a code review task.

Sigh.  The question was on-topic for fortran.  The question is clear to those versed in Fortran.  The individual, who did the migration, seems to have latched on to one or two words used by the OP in his question and completely neglected that there was active on-going commentary (not a discussion).  If comments are ignored by those with the power to migrate a question, then why even offer an "Add a comment" capability.  So, yes, it is alienating when one goes to follow-up and is suddenly redirect to another location (not a forum) where he can no longer post.

@steve It's not clear why you are saying that you would be unable to post on Code Review. I also don't see the relevance of comments to migration: either the question is on-topic here, and shouldn't be migrated (seemingly the current consensus, as it's been reopened) or it's off-topic and may be migrated (assuming it's on-topic at the target site, which it seemingly was not).  The issue is topicality; the comments are completely orthogonal to that (and in any case, the last comment, nearly 2 hours pre-migration, did not request any follow-up from the asker).

@RyanM,  I followed the link to the migrated question.  Entered a comment to expand upon Fortran's named construct feature.  Went to post and was informed that I needed to "Create an Account or Log in".  I was already logged into SO.  This suggests that I needed to create yet another account (or be inconvenienced with logging in yet again if my SO account is works on CR).  If the moderator had actually read the first 2 comments, they would know that the question was on-topic and it was actively being address.  You notice that an "Answer" has not been submitted.  It takes time to write one!

Too few characters allowed for my last reply.  I do find the herd mentality of the mods interesting.  It's okay to say "Yeah. we messed up."

@steve You're still missing the point: the fact that it was "actively being addressed" is irrelevant. An off-topic question that's being addressed is still off-topic, and an on-topic question obviously shouldn't be migrated regardless. All that happened in this particular instance was that a mod made a mistake, that doesn't mean that comments or answers have any bearing on migration in general.

@JohnMontgomery, thanks for your time.  I'll not respond to any additional post here.  I'll likely stop responding to post in SO [fortran] and [gfortran].  Nothing like kicking someone with 39 years of Fortran program experience and 25+ year of contributing to and helping maintain what is likely the most used Fortran compiler on the planet to the curb.
